# Processing emails with python (issues with quotations)

Tags: python, parsing, email

I'm trying to process my emails with python (but anything that does the job I'm describing will do, really).

I can connect to the imap server, download messages... It's all fine.

But for a given mail, if it is a reply to a previous one, it will probably embed all the conversation that has already happened. The problem is that I don't see any pattern in the way people and softwares handle this. People do top/bottom/middle quote and softwares may use HTML for quotes or plain text (with ">").

My goal is to only separate what the user has actually typed in his email. I do not need what he or she was referring to (headers can help me with that).

Is there a lib out there that could help me?

Comment: Related question: [Parse email content from quoted reply](http://stackoverflow.com/q/278788/222914)